# python regular expressions using the re module can you write a regex which looks inside the result of another regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am wanting to write a regular expression which pulls out the following from between but not including `<p>` and `</p>` tags:

begins with the word "Cash" has some stuff I don't want then a number $336,008.

From:

> `<p>Cash nbs $13,000</p>`

**I want "Cash" and if available (maybe 0 or nothing) the number.**

What I have so far gets me everything inside of the `<p>` tags including the tags themselves.

```
\<p\>(|.*Cash.*|.*Total.*\$\d+.*)\<\/p\>
```

Comment: Try `(Cash|Total)[^<$]*(\$\d+(?:,\d+)*)?`. But it would be best if you could serve the string without the tags.

Comment: unfortunately can't serve it without the tags

Comment: for getting data from html and xml you should use a parser and not regular expressions! Look up the beautifulsoup module here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: I've used beautifulsoup and want to extract some text from the data which beautifulsoup has captured using the regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you using re.findall, just use () with you want to catch.

```
>>> test = '<p>Cash nbs $13,000</p>'
>>> re.findall(r'<p>(Cash).+\${1}\d*|\,</p>', test)
['Cash']
```